# NetBeans/Symfony2 gives "unused use statement" warnings when using FOSRestBundle namespaces

Tags: symfony, netbeans, annotations, warnings, fosrestbundle

I have the following set up on my PC,
Ubuntu: 13.10,
NetBeans: 8.0,
Symfony: 2.4.3,
FOSRestBundle: 1.3.0,

and I have a "false" warning "unused use statement" in my code:

```
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations;
```

where later I have,

```
/**
/* @Annotations\View()
*/
public function someFunction(){}
```

The code is working, if I just ignore the warning; however, If I use NetBeans feature "Fix Uses (CTRL+SHIFT+I), the required use statement would be deleted.

I found a relevant bug archive here: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=212932
but the bug has status as resolved.

Other Symfony annotations work fine, e.g. the @Route annotation from Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route

I would like to know if there is any way to remove the "false" warning on my use statement.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You must check an option in NetBeans :

Tools -> Options -> PHP -> Annotations
     -> Treat unknown annotation as Type Annotation

(after you check, close your file, then reopen it)

Comment: Great, and I've been looking for this answer for a long time :)